# ROS supported for video feeds from 2 robots

Tags: ros, stream, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, may i know whether ROS is able to support video feed streaming from 2 robots at the same time? or have to do with 1 robot at a time?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223442/ros-supported-for-video-feeds-from-2-robots/) by [yteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25472/yteo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In theory, the image transport library in ROS supports an unlimited number of video streams and an unlimited number of robots.

In practice, the number of simultaneous video streams that you can have will probably be limited by your network bandwidth.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yteo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25472/yteo/) on 2016-01-04**:
hi, for the multiple of ardrones, is it possible to do so? because i have tried with 2 ardrones at the same time, i still have some issue with video streaming.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-01-04**:
That is a completely different question. I'd suggest that you ask a new question and carefully describe the specific problem you're having.